# Incorrect Operand Type in Dynamo DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

[Dynamo DB table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkCpt.png)

I am trying to append a list to the "Hi" List , but coming up with invalid operator type in the list_append call, which says one of them is a Map but these still look list to me ...

Here is the API call :

```
response =    node_table.update_item(
              TableName='xyz',
              Key={......},
              UpdateExpression='SET #ri = list_append(:vals, #ri)',
              ExpressionAttributeNames={'#ri':'Hello.Hi'},
              ExpressionAttributeValues={":vals": {"L": [ { "S": "Something" }]}})
```

Error: Invalid UpdateExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator or function: list_append, operand type: M

I referred [DynamoDB : SET list_append not working using aws sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33278475/dynamodb-set-list-append-not-working-using-aws-sdk), but could not figure out

Please let me know what am I missing

Comment: Screenshot for the table is named as Dynamo DB table

Comment: You copied it wrong from the reference you mentioned: it needs to be `list_append(#ri, :vals)`

Comment: It can be either way :)

Answer (score 5):

Looking at your table, `Hi` is a List of *Maps*.  You're trying to update it with a List of *Strings* here:

```
 ExpressionAttributeValues={":vals": {"L": [ { "S": "Something" }]}})
```

That seems to be what the error message is trying to say.

Comment: @dheerajtripathi if I answered your question, please accept the answer.

Comment: Yes, upvoted it :), looks like I am not reputed enough to upvote, but yes that was the answer

Answer (score 0):

As Matt pointed out the String constraint was infact the error ,

Here is the correct version

```
response =  node_table.update_item(
        TableName='xyz',
        Key={'..},
        UpdateExpression='SET #ri = list_append(:vals, #ri)',
        ExpressionAttributeNames={'#ri':'Hello.Hi'},
        ExpressionAttributeValues={":vals": ["Something"]})
```